# How to iterate through pages without nextpage button in html tag in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, for-loop, selenium-webdriver, while-loop

Please I need your help with this. I working on a scraping project.

Here's the web link that I am trying to scrap the *Outputs* tab of this address: `https://www.napier.ac.uk/research-and-innovation/research-search?fv=BE7C946393454607AD2CC3D91E65303F%7eBusiness+School&dtFrom=2021-01&dtTo=2022-12&t1sz=100&tab=1&tabpg1=3#rms`

I am able to scrape the *firstpage* and the *nextpage*(which could be page 2, or 3) but I'm unable to *iterate* through the pages. Maybe because there's no *nextpage* button on the HTML tag.

**This is what I have done**

```
output_tab = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='r-tabs-anchor'][normalize-space()='Outputs'])[1]")))
output_tab.click()
time.sleep(2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': [''], 'SubTitle': [''], 'Abstract': [''], 'Intro': [''], 'Links': ['']})

counter = 0
while counter < 4:
    
    driver.refresh()
    post_blocks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='output bgGrey'])")
    
    for post_block in post_blocks:
        title = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div/h3").text # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div/h3
        sub_title = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[3]").text # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div[3]
        try:
            post_abstract = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[4]").text # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div[4]
        except Exception:
            continue
        try:
            post_intro = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[5]").text # # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div[5]
        except Exception:
            continue
        post_link = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./parent::a").get_attribute('href') # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/parent::a
        
        df = df.append({'Titles': title, 'SubTitle': sub_title, 'Abstract': post_abstract, 'Intro': post_intro, 'Links': post_link}, ignore_index = True)
    
        
    next_page = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[contains(@class,'')][normalize-space()='3'])[2]"))).click()
   
    counter += 1
    


df.to_csv('C:/Users/testuser/napier_outputs.csv')
```

**Error Noticed**
`TimeoutException: TimedPromise timed out after 300000 ms`

I can easily scrap the pages by changing the value in this *XPATH* `(//a[contains(@class,'')][normalize-space()='3'])[2]` from *3* to *4*. And so on.

In summary, how can I iterate through the pages and collect the data as I have done for the first page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could determine the number of pages at the beginning by analyzing the link to the "Last" page. This `<a>` element's `href` attribute contains the the query parameter `tabpg1` whichs value is equal to the number of pages.
With this knowledge, you can now retrieve all pages by defining a base url to which you add the counter. Check this code:

```
import urllib.parse

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,3)
counter = 1
base_url = "https://www.napier.ac.uk/research-and-innovation/research-search?fv=BE7C946393454607AD2CC3D91E65303F%7eBusiness+School&dtFrom=2021-01&dtTo=2022-12&t1sz=100&tab=1&tabpg1="
driver.get(f"{base_url}{counter}")

output_tab = wait.until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='r-tabs-anchor'][normalize-space()='Outputs'])[1]")))
output_tab.click()
time.sleep(2)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Titles': [], 'SubTitle': [], 'Abstract': [], 'Intro': [], 'Links': []})

# get number of pages
last_link = driver.find_element(By.ID, "bodycontent_1_ctl07_lnkLast")
url_parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(last_link.get_attribute("href"))
last_page = int(urllib.parse.parse_qs(url_parts.query)["tabpg1"][0])

while counter <= last_page:
    
    driver.refresh()
    post_blocks = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='output bgGrey'])")
    
    for post_block in post_blocks:
        title = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div/h3").text # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div/h3
        sub_title = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[3]").text # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div[3]
        try:
            post_abstract = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[4]").text # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div[4]
        except Exception:
            continue
        try:
            post_intro = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./div[5]").text # # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/div[5]
        except Exception:
            continue
        post_link = post_block.find_element(By.XPATH, "./parent::a").get_attribute('href') # (//div[@class='output bgGrey'])/parent::a
        
        df = df.append({'Titles': title, 'SubTitle': sub_title, 'Abstract': post_abstract, 'Intro': post_intro, 'Links': post_link}, ignore_index = True)
    
    counter += 1
    driver.get(f"{base_url}{counter}")
    

df.to_csv('napier_outputs.csv')
```